# BeautifulSoup soup.prettify() gives strange output

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to parse a web site and I'm going to use it later in my Django project. To do that, I'm using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup4. However, I couldn't get what I want. The output of BeautifulSoup object is weird. I tried different pages, it worked (output is normal). I thought it is because of the page. Then, when my friend tried to do the same thing, he got normal output. I couldn't manage to figure out problem.

This is the [website](http://kafemud.bilkent.edu.tr/monu_tr.html) I'm going to parse.

This is an example of the weird output after the command "soup.prettify()":

```
t   d       B   G   C   O   L   O   R   =   "   #   9   9   0   4   0   4   "       w   i   d   t   h   =   "   3   "   &gt;   i   m   g       S   R   C   =   "   1   p   .   g   i   f   "       A   L   T       B   O   R   D   E   R   =   "   0   "       h   e   i   g   h   t   =   "   1   "       w   i   d   t   h   =   "   3   "   &gt;   /   t   d   &gt;   \n           /   t   r   &gt;   \n           t   r   &gt;   \n                   t   d       c   o   l   s   p   a   n   =   "   3   "       B   G   C   O   L   O   R   =   "   #   9   9   0   4   0   4   "       w   i   d   t   h   =   "   6   0   0   "       h   e   i   g   h   t   =   "   3   "   &gt;   i   m   g       s   r   c   =   "   1   p   .   g   i   f   "       w   i   d   t   h   =   "   6   0   0   "   \n                   h   e   i   g   h   t   =   "   1   "   &gt;   /   t   d   &gt;   \n           /   t   r   &gt;   \n   /   t   a   b   l   e   &gt;   \n   /   c   e   n   t   e   r   &gt;   /   d   i   v   &gt;   \n   \n   p   &gt;   &amp;n   b   s   p   ;   &amp;n   b   s   p   ;   &amp;n   b   s   p   ;   &amp;n   b   s   p   ;   /   p   &gt;   \n   /   b   o   d   y   &gt;   \n   /   h   t   m   l   &gt;\n  </p>\n </body>\n</html>'
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used?

Comment: It is similar to what @Hooked wrote. Here is what I used:

import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.open( "http://kafemud.bilkent.edu.tr/monu_tr.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup( page)
print soup.prettify()

Answer (score 7):

Here is a minimal example that *does* work for me, including the snippet of html that you have a problem with. It's hard to tell without your code, but my guess is you did something like `' '.join(A.split())` somewhere.

```
import urllib2, bs4

url = "http://kafemud.bilkent.edu.tr/monu_tr.html"
req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
raw = req.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(raw)

print soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')
```

Giving:

```
....
<td bgcolor="#990404" width="3">
       <img alt="" border="0" src="1p.gif" width="3"/>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="TOP">
       <div align="left">
        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" valign="TOP" width="594">
         <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top">
           <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="icerik" width="574">
....
```

Comment: It gave the same weird output on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you and your friend use different parsers. BeautifulSoup will use the parser it considers "best", and thus prefer `lxml` for speed reasons (if installed).  If using recent versions of Python (and the last version of the included parser), there are cases which are handled better by `BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')`; this is the case e.g. when there are unmasked `<` characters (instead of `&lt;`) in text content.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have your XML coming in with an encoding that beautifulsoup isn't expecting. My guess is that your XML is in UTF-16 and beautifulsoup is reading it as UTF-8. Python offers the .encode and .decode functions for switching between different encodings. Something like

```
myXmlStr.encode("utf-16").decode("utf-8")
```

Would probably solve your problem if the issue is your incoming XML encoding. I'm new to beautiful soup myself, but a quick google suggests that if the  problem is the encoding of the output, prettify accepts an encoding parameter:

```
soup.prettify("utf-16")
```

Without more information I can't give you a clearer answer - but hopefully this points you in a helpful direction.